# jQuery Tools Scrollable prev/next browse arrows appear on hover?

Tags: hover, show-hide, jquery-tools

I'm using the [jQuery Tools Scrollable & Navigator plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/navigator.html). I searched their forums but couldn't find an answer (and can't post there because it's disabled "due to spamming").

My question is, is there a way for the prev/next browser arrows to only display on hover over Scrollable? In other words, if the cursor is off of Scrollable, the arrows disappear.

[Here's my page](http://bit.ly/AcGXzT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Syntax to be used
//$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut); 

$('.scrollable').hover(function(){
    $('.browse').fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $('.browse').fadeOut();
});
```

CSS Needed:

```
a.browse.prev, a.browse.next{display:none;}
```

You may need to remove the `display:block` from you a.browse in your css file for the `display:none` to work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Eric - thanks for your reply. I set display none on .prev & .next in the css file (bit.ly/AA8JH5) and added your script to the js file (bit.ly/yy9UB0). Unfortunately nothing's changed :/ Do I need to change "selector" to something else in the first line? If I delete the first line hovering over either arrow makes it appear then disappear. Any other ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: My apologies, the first line i posted was the syntax to be used. I should have stated not to use that in your code. Let me look at your site to see you actual selectors and see if I can help you out more.

Comment: Check out my edit to this post. It should help you more. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I added the new js, css and removed display:block from a.browse, and the same weird thing is happening in that the arrows will fade in and then quickly fade back out during hover. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Let me give this another try, I believe if you change the $('.scrollable') to $('#slider') it should fix that flashing issue - hopefully. Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: Not a problem, I'm glad I could help.